# Logs sobre S3 y S2

Tags: aws, log

Vengo con una consulta, tengo que analizar unos logs de aws, y quería saber como es el log para la eliminación(baja de imagen del servidor) de S3 o S2, para crear usuarios o para asignar roles Y si habría alguno mas al que le tendría que poner mas ojo

Answer (score 0):

Prácticamente toda actividad que implique la modificación de un recurso de AWS deja su traza. Estos logs se pueden consultar en el servicio CloudTrail.

Si tienes acceso al id del recurso puedes buscar por dicho id y te aparecerán todas las operaciones que se hayan realizado sobre dicho recurso.